# If I open konsole it opens non-stop more windows of konsole

Tags: debian, kde, application, bugs

If I open konsole it opens non-stop more windows of konsole and the gui hangs because of overload, I tried `apt purge konsole && apt install konsole`, I tried to restart but to no avail.

**EDIT:** @RuiFRibeiro

Here is the contents of ~youruser/.config/konsolerc

```
[Desktop Entry]
 2 DefaultProfile=programmer.profile
 3
 4 [Favorite Profiles]
 5 Favorites=programmer.profile
 6
 7 [KFileDialog Settings]
 8 Recent Files[$e]=gott.png,file:$HOME/Pictures/trinity_the_matrix-11351.jpg,file:$HOME/Pictures/gott.png
 9 Recent URLs[$e]=file:$HOME/Pictures/
10
11 [MainWindow]
12 Height 1024=625
13 State=AAAA/wAAAAD9AAAAAAAABQAAAAOhAAAABAAAAAQAAAAIAAAACPwAAAAA
14 ToolBarsMovable=Disabled
15 Width 1280=845
16 Window-Maximized 1024x1280=true
17
18 [Notification Messages]
19 CloseAllTabs=true
```

Comment: Check in your `~/.bash_login` or `~/.bashrc` if `konsole` gets called in some way.

Comment: @MrShunz No nothing there

Comment: @MrShunz It's like having a virus on the system

Comment: `konsole` depends on `konsole-kpart`, may it be the problem?? I got few problems with KDE usualy caused with mad user config files. I such case I create new user and 98% of problems dismis with login as new user.

Comment: @schweik it happened after first time loging in as new user and when i came back to my account konsole was firing like crazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from your previous [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466855/i-this-output-from-who-a-normal/466860), it seems `konsole` is calling itself.

I would view the contents of `~youruser/.config/konsolerc` and delete it to fix the problem.