# Is this output from “who -a” normal?

Tags: debian, login, tty, konsole, pts

This does not look normal to me:

```
who -a
           system boot  2018-09-04 11:59
LOGIN      tty1         2018-09-04 11:59               685 id=tty1
           run-level 5  2018-09-04 11:59
user + pts/0        2018-09-04 20:39   .         19612 (192.168.1.173)
user + pts/1        2018-09-04 12:15 08:27        9252 (:0)
           pts/2        2018-09-04 13:02             12256 id=ts/2  term=0 exit=0
           pts/3        2018-09-04 13:02             12265 id=ts/3  term=0 exit=0
           pts/4        2018-09-04 13:02             12274 id=ts/4  term=0 exit=0
           pts/5        2018-09-04 13:02             12283 id=ts/5  term=0 exit=0
           pts/6        2018-09-04 13:02             12293 id=ts/6  term=0 exit=0
           pts/7        2018-09-04 13:02             12302 id=ts/7  term=0 exit=0
           pts/8        2018-09-04 13:02             12311 id=ts/8  term=0 exit=0
           pts/9        2018-09-04 13:02             12320 id=ts/9  term=0 exit=0
           pts/10       2018-09-04 13:02             12329 id=s/10  term=0 exit=0
           pts/11       2018-09-04 13:02             12338 id=s/11  term=0 exit=0
           pts/12       2018-09-04 13:02             12347 id=s/12  term=0 exit=0
           pts/14       2018-09-04 12:39             11677 id=s/14  term=0 exit=0
           pts/15       2018-09-04 12:39             11687 id=s/15  term=0 exit=0
           pts/18       2018-09-04 12:18             10435 id=s/18  term=0 exit=0
           pts/22       2018-09-04 12:03              5066 id=s/22  term=0 exit=0
           pts/23       2018-09-04 12:03              5075 id=s/23  term=0 exit=0
           pts/24       2018-09-04 12:03              5084 id=s/24  term=0 exit=0
           pts/25       2018-09-04 12:03              5093 id=s/25  term=0 exit=0
           pts/26       2018-09-04 12:03              5102 id=s/26  term=0 exit=0
           pts/27       2018-09-04 12:03              5112 id=s/27  term=0 exit=0
           pts/28       2018-09-04 12:03              5121 id=s/28  term=0 exit=0
           pts/29       2018-09-04 12:03              5130 id=s/29  term=0 exit=0
           pts/30       2018-09-04 12:03              5139 id=s/30  term=0 exit=0
           pts/31       2018-09-04 12:03              5148 id=s/31  term=0 exit=0
           pts/32       2018-09-04 12:03              5157 id=s/32  term=0 exit=0
           pts/33       2018-09-04 12:03              5166 id=s/33  term=0 exit=0
           pts/34       2018-09-04 12:03              5175 id=s/34  term=0 exit=0
           pts/35       2018-09-04 12:03              5184 id=s/35  term=0 exit=0
           pts/36       2018-09-04 12:03              5193 id=s/36  term=0 exit=0
           pts/46       2018-09-04 12:00              2093 id=s/46  term=0 exit=0
           pts/47       2018-09-04 12:00              2102 id=s/47  term=0 exit=0
           pts/48       2018-09-04 12:00              2111 id=s/48  term=0 exit=0
           pts/49       2018-09-04 12:00              2120 id=s/49  term=0 exit=0
           pts/50       2018-09-04 12:00              2129 id=s/50  term=0 exit=0
           pts/51       2018-09-04 12:00              2138 id=s/51  term=0 exit=0
           pts/52       2018-09-04 12:00              2147 id=s/52  term=0 exit=0
           pts/53       2018-09-04 12:00              2156 id=s/53  term=0 exit=0
           pts/54       2018-09-04 12:00              2165 id=s/54  term=0 exit=0
           pts/55       2018-09-04 12:00              2174 id=s/55  term=0 exit=0
           pts/56       2018-09-04 12:00              2183 id=s/56  term=0 exit=0
           pts/57       2018-09-04 12:00              2192 id=s/57  term=0 exit=0
           pts/58       2018-09-04 12:00              2201 id=s/58  term=0 exit=0
           pts/59       2018-09-04 12:00              2210 id=s/59  term=0 exit=0
           pts/60       2018-09-04 12:00              2219 id=s/60  term=0 exit=0
           pts/61       2018-09-04 12:00              2228 id=s/61  term=0 exit=0
           pts/62       2018-09-04 12:00              2238 id=s/62  term=0 exit=0
           pts/63       2018-09-04 12:00              2247 id=s/63  term=0 exit=0
           pts/64       2018-09-04 12:00              2256 id=s/64  term=0 exit=0
           pts/65       2018-09-04 12:00              2265 id=s/65  term=0 exit=0
           pts/66       2018-09-04 12:00              2274 id=s/66  term=0 exit=0
           pts/67       2018-09-04 12:00              2283 id=s/67  term=0 exit=0
           pts/68       2018-09-04 12:00              2292 id=s/68  term=0 exit=0
           pts/69       2018-09-04 12:00              2301 id=s/69  term=0 exit=0
           pts/70       2018-09-04 12:00              2310 id=s/70  term=0 exit=0
           pts/71       2018-09-04 12:00              2319 id=s/71  term=0 exit=0
           pts/72       2018-09-04 12:00              2328 id=s/72  term=0 exit=0
           pts/73       2018-09-04 12:00              2337 id=s/73  term=0 exit=0
           pts/74       2018-09-04 12:00              2346 id=s/74  term=0 exit=0
           pts/75       2018-09-04 12:00              2355 id=s/75  term=0 exit=0
           pts/76       2018-09-04 12:00              2364 id=s/76  term=0 exit=0
           pts/77       2018-09-04 12:00              2373 id=s/77  term=0 exit=0
           pts/78       2018-09-04 12:00              2403 id=s/78  term=0 exit=0
           pts/79       2018-09-04 12:00              2412 id=s/79  term=0 exit=0
           pts/80       2018-09-04 12:00              2421 id=s/80  term=0 exit=0
           pts/81       2018-09-04 12:00              2431 id=s/81  term=0 exit=0
           pts/82       2018-09-04 12:00              2440 id=s/82  term=0 exit=0
           pts/83       2018-09-04 12:00              2449 id=s/83  term=0 exit=0
           pts/84       2018-09-04 12:00              2458 id=s/84  term=0 exit=0
           pts/85       2018-09-04 12:00              2467 id=s/85  term=0 exit=0
           pts/86       2018-09-04 12:00              2476 id=s/86  term=0 exit=0
           pts/87       2018-09-04 12:00              2485 id=s/87  term=0 exit=0
           pts/88       2018-09-04 12:00              2494 id=s/88  term=0 exit=0
           pts/89       2018-09-04 12:00              2503 id=s/89  term=0 exit=0
           pts/90       2018-09-04 12:00              2512 id=s/90  term=0 exit=0
           pts/91       2018-09-04 12:00              2521 id=s/91  term=0 exit=0
           pts/92       2018-09-04 12:00              2530 id=s/92  term=0 exit=0
           pts/93       2018-09-04 12:00              2539 id=s/93  term=0 exit=0
           pts/94       2018-09-04 12:00              2548 id=s/94  term=0 exit=0
           pts/95       2018-09-04 12:00              2599 id=s/95  term=0 exit=0
           pts/96       2018-09-04 12:00              2657 id=s/96  term=0 exit=0
           pts/97       2018-09-04 12:00              2710 id=s/97  term=0 exit=0
           pts/98       2018-09-04 12:00              2755 id=s/98  term=0 exit=0
           pts/99       2018-09-04 12:00              2784 id=s/99  term=0 exit=0
           pts/100      2018-09-04 12:00              2809 id=/100  term=0 exit=0
           pts/101      2018-09-04 12:00              2818 id=/101  term=0 exit=0
           pts/102      2018-09-04 12:00              2827 id=/102  term=0 exit=0
           pts/103      2018-09-04 12:00              2836 id=/103  term=0 exit=0
           pts/104      2018-09-04 12:00              2845 id=/104  term=0 exit=0
           pts/105      2018-09-04 12:00              2854 id=/105  term=0 exit=0
           pts/106      2018-09-04 12:00              2863 id=/106  term=0 exit=0
           pts/107      2018-09-04 12:00              2872 id=/107  term=0 exit=0
           pts/108      2018-09-04 12:00              2881 id=/108  term=0 exit=0
           pts/109      2018-09-04 12:00              2890 id=/109  term=0 exit=0
           pts/110      2018-09-04 12:00              2899 id=/110  term=0 exit=0
           pts/111      2018-09-04 12:00              2908 id=/111  term=0 exit=0
           pts/112      2018-09-04 12:00              2917 id=/112  term=0 exit=0
           pts/113      2018-09-04 12:00              2926 id=/113  term=0 exit=0
           pts/114      2018-09-04 12:00              2935 id=/114  term=0 exit=0
           pts/115      2018-09-04 12:00              2944 id=/115  term=0 exit=0
           pts/116      2018-09-04 12:00              2953 id=/116  term=0 exit=0
           pts/117      2018-09-04 12:00              2962 id=/117  term=0 exit=0
           pts/118      2018-09-04 12:00              2971 id=/118  term=0 exit=0
           pts/119      2018-09-04 12:00              2981 id=/119  term=0 exit=0
           pts/120      2018-09-04 12:00              2990 id=/120  term=0 exit=0
           pts/121      2018-09-04 12:00              2999 id=/121  term=0 exit=0
           pts/122      2018-09-04 12:00              3008 id=/122  term=0 exit=0
           pts/123      2018-09-04 12:00              3017 id=/123  term=0 exit=0
           pts/124      2018-09-04 12:00              3026 id=/124  term=0 exit=0
           pts/125      2018-09-04 12:00              3035 id=/125  term=0 exit=0
           pts/126      2018-09-04 12:00              3044 id=/126  term=0 exit=0
           pts/127      2018-09-04 12:00              3053 id=/127  term=0 exit=0
           pts/128      2018-09-04 12:00              3062 id=/128  term=0 exit=0
           pts/129      2018-09-04 12:00              3071 id=/129  term=0 exit=0
           pts/130      2018-09-04 12:00              3080 id=/130  term=0 exit=0
           pts/131      2018-09-04 12:00              3089 id=/131  term=0 exit=0
           pts/132      2018-09-04 12:00              3098 id=/132  term=0 exit=0
           pts/133      2018-09-04 12:00              3107 id=/133  term=0 exit=0
           pts/134      2018-09-04 12:00              3116 id=/134  term=0 exit=0
           pts/135      2018-09-04 12:00              3125 id=/135  term=0 exit=0
           pts/136      2018-09-04 12:00              3134 id=/136  term=0 exit=0
           pts/137      2018-09-04 12:00              3145 id=/137  term=0 exit=0
           pts/138      2018-09-04 12:00              3154 id=/138  term=0 exit=0
           pts/139      2018-09-04 12:00              3163 id=/139  term=0 exit=0
           pts/140      2018-09-04 12:00              3172 id=/140  term=0 exit=0
           pts/141      2018-09-04 12:00              3181 id=/141  term=0 exit=0
           pts/142      2018-09-04 12:00              3190 id=/142  term=0 exit=0
           pts/143      2018-09-04 12:00              3199 id=/143  term=0 exit=0
           pts/144      2018-09-04 12:00              3208 id=/144  term=0 exit=0
           pts/145      2018-09-04 12:00              3217 id=/145  term=0 exit=0
           pts/146      2018-09-04 12:00              3226 id=/146  term=0 exit=0
           pts/147      2018-09-04 12:00              3235 id=/147  term=0 exit=0
           pts/148      2018-09-04 12:00              3244 id=/148  term=0 exit=0
           pts/149      2018-09-04 12:00              3253 id=/149  term=0 exit=0
           pts/150      2018-09-04 12:00              3262 id=/150  term=0 exit=0
           pts/151      2018-09-04 12:00              3271 id=/151  term=0 exit=0
           pts/152      2018-09-04 12:00              3280 id=/152  term=0 exit=0
           pts/153      2018-09-04 12:00              3289 id=/153  term=0 exit=0
           pts/154      2018-09-04 12:00              3299 id=/154  term=0 exit=0
           pts/155      2018-09-04 12:00              3308 id=/155  term=0 exit=0
           pts/156      2018-09-04 12:00              3317 id=/156  term=0 exit=0
```

**QUESTION:**
What does this mean?

[I have another crazy problem on this system.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466751/if-i-open-konsole-it-opens-non-stop-more-windows-of-konsole?noredirect=1#comment850212_466751)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having this many pseudo-terminals open is a symptom of the question you are linking to.

Interestingly enough, when you call `konsole` from another terminal, say `lxterminal` in my case, it does not open another pseudo terminal.

However, when you open `konsole` from `konsole` it opens another pseudo-terminal each time you do that.

So, what seems it is happening is that `konsole` is opening `konsole` in a sort of a loop.